# android-How to change app name on phone's language

Tags: android

I've seen this in some apps , for example when the language is english , the app's name is in english but when the phone's language is changed to arabic for example ,it changes the application name to arabic .

By application name, I mean the name of app in the phone not when it opens .

How can I do so ?

Comment: why cant you change it in strings.xml

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder inside "res" call it `values-ar` for arabic language inside that folder create a string file `string.xml` put your app name like this:

```
<string name="app_name">السلة</string>
```

then in your Manifest file change app tag : `android:label="@string/app_name"`

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Specify the label in your manifest's application tag as shown below:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Now put the app_name in all the different strings files.
This will surely change the name of the application when you change the language of the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by settings `strings.xml` for every language you want to add.
[image]

Now ensure that inside to any xml you will have in resources `<string name="app_name">Your_app_name</string>`

Comment: *You can achieve that by setting strings.xml